# How to rank and select rows by row variance in R

Tags: r, list, data-analysis, rank, variance

I have a R list like below:

```
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 6.939576 0.9102779 2.513760 3.838500 8.017567
[2,] 4.134372 2.1731401 6.627487 6.202576 9.603031
[3,] 6.303585 6.9664992 1.861797 3.507445 1.822297
[4,] 4.675198 4.2120635 6.429899 8.439339 9.593823
[5,] 6.472145 3.2654931 7.416211 2.056762 1.988843
[6,] 7.329604 3.8279722 5.085237 1.158770 1.278410
```

I want to select top 3 rows with the highest **variance**, which should be,

```
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 6.939576 0.9102779 2.513760 3.838500 8.017567
[2,] 4.134372 2.1731401 6.627487 6.202576 9.603031
[6,] 7.329604 3.8279722 5.085237 1.158770 1.278410
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: hi can you please use dput on your data, this format is kind of hard to copy and paste

Comment: Hello @Marting, please in next questions do this: type `dput(dataset)` in the console (I assume your data is named "dataset") and copy the output and paste it in the question. This help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi martin I am going to assume that you can create a data.frame

```r
library(tidyverse)

original_df <- data.table::fread("6.939576 0.9102779 2.513760 3.838500 8.017567
4.134372 2.1731401 6.627487 6.202576 9.603031
6.303585 6.9664992 1.861797 3.507445 1.822297
4.675198 4.2120635 6.429899 8.439339 9.593823
6.472145 3.2654931 7.416211 2.056762 1.988843
7.329604 3.8279722 5.085237 1.158770 1.278410")


original_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(variance = c_across(everything()) %>% var()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(n = 3, order_by = variance)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 variance
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  6.94 0.910  2.51  3.84  8.02     8.89
#> 2  4.13 2.17   6.63  6.20  9.60     7.81
#> 3  7.33 3.83   5.09  1.16  1.28     6.86
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you need a really fast vectorized code matrixStats package has a vectorized variance function

```r
original_df %>%
  mutate(variance = across(everything()) %>% as.matrix() %>% matrixStats::rowVars(.)) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 3, order_by = variance)
```

Comment: I just re-edit the data format but I'm not sure whether it's the format you want. By the way, your answer perfectly solve my question! Many thanks!

Comment: Oh no problem please consider voting on it and accepting it as the answer

Comment: @Bruno great answer, just a question, to read marting data did you have to copy each line and paste into `fread`? do you know if there is a way to read OPs data without copying their data line by line?

Comment: @Alexis I did copy and paste, edited the brackets and numbers out and used that inside fread, if you want you can then paste into excel and the use datapasta to copy it into your script in multiple formats

Comment: Obrigado Bruno!, it's a little tedious to read data in such manner, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah that is why I asked op to change the format that he posted the data

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how you define variance I will assume it could be operationalized as the difference between minimum and maximum value.

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = rnorm(10),
  v2 = rnorm(10),
  v3 = rnorm(10),
  v4 = rnorm(10)
)
```

Solution:

```
df$variance <- apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x))
df[order(df$variance, decreasing = T),]
```

Result:

```
            v1         v2         v3          v4  variance
6   1.71506499  1.7869131 -1.6866933  0.68864025 3.4736064
3   1.55870831  0.4007715 -1.0260044  0.89512566 2.5847128
1  -0.56047565  1.2240818 -1.0678237  0.42646422 2.2919055
8  -1.26506123 -1.9666172  0.1533731 -0.06191171 2.1199903
9  -0.68685285  0.7013559 -1.1381369 -0.30596266 1.8394928
10 -0.44566197 -0.4727914  1.2538149 -0.38047100 1.7266063
4   0.07050839  0.1106827 -0.7288912  0.87813349 1.6070247
5   0.12928774 -0.5558411 -0.6250393  0.82158108 1.4466203
2  -0.23017749  0.3598138 -0.2179749 -0.29507148 0.6548853
7   0.46091621  0.4978505  0.8377870  0.55391765 0.3768708
```

Alternatively you could operationalize variance by calculating the standard deviation `sd`:

```
df$variance <- apply(df, 1, sd)
```

or simply by using `var`:

```
df$variance <- apply(df, 1, var)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. tbh my data is also created randomly. For variance I mean just calculate by var(). But thanks for your advice!

Comment: Have edited the answer. Please consider accepting it by clicking the tick in the left upper corner of the answer.